# EF Core 6 - when using Contains in the where clause causes an error "could not be translated"

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am migrating from EF Core 2.1 to EF Core 6.

I have the following code:

```
var currentCars = _context.Cars
                          .Include(x => x.Model)
                          .Where(x => currentModels.Contains(x.ModelId))
                          .ToList();
```

`Cars` have a `ModelId`(long) that relates to a `Model` type.

`CurrentModels` is a `List<long>`, being the current model type Ids we are interested in.

> The LINQ expression 'EnumerableQuery { 1 }
> .Contains(NavigationTreeExpression
> Value: EntityReference: AssetSP | IncludePaths:
> Root
> -> Model
> Expression: a.ModelId)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I can't work out how to do the query on the database. I do not want to bring all the Cars back to the server to filter there.

In SQL it would be something like.

```
Select * 
From Cars 
Where ModelId in (-- ids here --)
```

Comment: Do you have `ValueConverter` applied to this column?

Comment: The attributes on the ModelId are

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ModelId")]

There is nothing else

Comment: `Contains` works for `List<long>` in EF Core 6, just tested locally for SQL Server. Are you using some other provider? Also, please show your code for how `currentModels` is defined. For debugging purpose, try replacing with `long[] currentModels = {1,2,3};` above that line and see what it translates to.